# How to use notify.js with a button in rails 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins

I am new in rails. I want to show notification using notify.js. I have downloaded the notify.js file and put it into app/assets/javascripts. Now
 
`<script>
   $.notify("Hello", "success" );
</script>`

works perfectly. But I want to perform this action after clicking a button.

`<%= link_to image_tag("done.png", :title => 'Mark as Done', :class => 'controller_images'), task_path(task), :method => :put  %>`

This is my code for button.

```
def create
@task = Task.new(task_params)
if @task.save
  redirect_to tasks_path, :notice => "Your new Task is added successfully!"

else
  render "new"
end
end
```

And this is the code of controller class for create new task. 
I want to use notify.js when a task is successfully created instead of using `:notice`

Someone please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an example, but not the best case I must say. I would rather, I inject the notice somewhere in the body and keep looking for any notice / error / other type notice and call the notify.js with the available parse data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
        var notice = "<%= flash[:notice] %>"
         $.notify(notice, "success" );
     })
</script>
```